# Not able to share full size image in facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a list images in my website, using facebook feed Javascript I'm sharing image to my FB wall. It works fine.

But It only shows me thumbnail(90x90) and client wants to show it in a full size or bigger image.

These are the tags currently using -

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%=@image%>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%=@title%>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%=@description%>"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="<%= @width %>" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="<%= @height %>" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] %>" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your code I understand I can say that you are trying to **share a URL** **not an Image**

Comment: Is there any way I can share Image instead of URL

Comment: Currently its sharing the small thumb, on clicking of it takes me to my website

Comment: You are **sharing an URL to Facebook timeline** not an Image.
You can share (Upload) image to timeline using their API.
When you share URLs to your timeline [Facebook Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me) reads the meta tags (`og:image` in your case)  in your `head` tags which generate an thumbnail to be shared along with your Post.. I hope that I made it clear for you & figure out what you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: Finally I achieved this with Facebook sharer which looks like it best suits to my requirement. Thanks Adam